# Changing Mysql golbal variable

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I am working on a `PERL` script that inserts multiple SQL statements.
As I am inserting 5000 rows in one insert so I have to increase the max_allowed_packet size.

When I run the script for the first time it gives an error
`packet size bigger than max_allowed_packet` but when it runs  again it doesn't give this error.

I have set the `autocommit=0` and execute commit after i execute the `$dbh->do("SET global max_allowed_packet=134217728") or $logger->error("Error :  $DBI::errstr");`

Do i specify this when i am connecting to the database ? 
Also it can be great if you can tell me an alternative to multiple insert statements.

P.S : I know I can make changes in the config files but i want to do it dynamically and i also know about prepare and execute statements.

Comment: its `Perl`, not `PERL`

Comment: I've read a lot about the subject. Many claim that it can be done, but it's only because they haven't tested it properly. The value needs to be set at connection time (no idea if Perl allows that), it cannot be changed with `SET global`, and it cannot be larger than the server-side value.

Answer (score 2):

i think what you want is like resolve this problem and keep your server running at the same time because if you would change the variable value in the config file then you have to restart the mysql server to make this change go live.

now it is clear from `$dbh->do("SET global max_allowed_packet=134217728") or $logger->error("Error : $DBI::errstr");` that it is a dynamic variable.

what you have to do is, Go to your mysql-server console and write the following command:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=134217728;
```

Now,you are done with updating of the value of the variable. you can see the value of this variable by the following query

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max%';
```

it will show you all the variables and their values with a prefix 'max'.
now you're done.

this information is best of my knowledge and hope this would also solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I know about this but I want to do this dynamically as the sript will be executed on different server(s).
So I dont want them to go and change from the console everytime.

Comment: the process i'd mentioned will do the things dynamically and as it is a global variable it will not change even after the restarting of the server.you've to log in to the each server and  in the every server you have to employ the same procedure.